# Add/Remove new Select w/ Options if Current Select w/ Options is selected

Tags: jquery

Ok I would like to be able to add another select box with the same options if the previous select box option is selected. If it's de-selected then remove the last select box w/ options.

Here is what I'm trying, I can add/remove another select box with the first select box but I can't with the newly created select box.

```
var counter = 1; // as we already have the first dropdown

function populate(selector) {
  $(selector)
    .append('<option value="foo">foo</option>')
    .append('<option value="bar">bar</option>')
}

populate('#select_options_1');

$("#select_options_" + counter).change( function() {
    var addNewSelect = $(this).val() != '';

    if(addNewSelect) {  
        counter++;      
        var newSelectOption = $(document.createElement('select')).attr("id", 'select_options_' + counter);

        newSelectOption.html('<option value="">Please Select an Option</option>' +
                             '<option value="foo">foo</option>' +
                             '<option value="bar">bar</option>');

        newSelectOption.appendTo("#select_option_groups");

    } else {
        $('#select_options_' + counter).remove();
        if(counter > 1) {
          counter--;
        } 
    }
    alert('Add New Select? ' + addNewSelect + ' Counter ' + counter);
});
```

The HTML

```
<div name="select_option_groups" id="select_option_groups">
    <select name="select_options_1" id="select_options_1">
        <option value="">Please Select an Option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Example Code from above: http://jsfiddle.net/RaHhY/31/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shorter solution, not sure if you're interested:

```
$(function(){
    var counter = 2;
    var onChange = function(e){
        val = $(':selected',this).val() || '';
        if (val != ''){
            // they may be able to toggle between valid options, too.
            // let's avoid that using a class we can apply
            var c = 'alreadyMadeASelection';
            if ($(this).hasClass(c))
                return;
            // now take the current select and clone it, then rename it
            var newSelect = $(this)
                .clone()
                .attr('name','select_options_'+counter++)
                .appendTo($(this).parent())
                .change(onChange);
            $(this).addClass(c);
        } else {
            var id = $(this).attr('name').match(/\d+$/), parent = $(this).parent();
            $(this).remove();

            // re-order the counter (we don't want missing numbers in the middle)
            $('select',parent).each(function(){
                var iid = $(this).attr('name').match(/\d+$/);
                if (iid>id)
                    $(this).attr('name','select_options_'+(iid-1));
            });
            counter--;
        }
    };
    $('#select_option_groups select').change(onChange);
});
```

Given the following:

```
<div id="select_option_groups">
    <select name="select_options_1">
        <option value="" selected>Please select an option</option>
        <option value="foo">Foo</option>
        <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UcrD8/2/)**

### Update

So much for shorter code :giggle:. Anyways, this is an update with a few basic improvements:

1. It will use the same select list HTML code (maintainable my only making a change to the HTML select, not the HTML and the javascript.
2. You can delete options at the end of the list, middle, beginning--it doesn't matter. The list will automatically re-order itself and decrement the counter.
3. An item is able to be modified after its initial selection without it having any effect on the list. (previously, if you selected foo then went back and selected bar it would add a new entry even though it wasn't a "new" value (just a modified one))

Comment: Oops, forgot to change the select's ID. But the point is to improve maintainability; you only have to change the html version of the select box and it will automatically clone itself.

Comment: I like the simple syntax but I need the counter as well. Also the live() is not working properly with the JQM (jQuery Mobile) lib, any alternatives?

Comment: @PhillPafford: I'm working on the counter now (actually, working on having them re-order so if you delete option 3, then 4 becomes 3, etc.) As for the .live, that's interesting but can be defeated easy.

Comment: works great except the JQM lib adds a bunch of other html elements around the select html for the CSS to display properly. Thanks for the efforts

Comment: @PhillPafford: Ah, just have to play with `.closest('ui-select')` and clone that instead. ;-) Probably also have to assign it an ID as well.

Comment: yeah I did all of that and I can replicate all the needed html and tags with the correct attributes. The look and feel is there but the functionality is missing, does nothing on the generated select options. Any thoughts? Here is some documentation on the lib: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/docs-forms.html#../../docs/forms/forms-selects.html

Comment: @PhillPafford: Looking through source now, I think I found a way to do it. Just need to add the new element to the container, then call JQM's "init" function on the new select (so it re-creates the html wrappers, the new menu, etc).

Comment: Hmm could you give an example? $(newSelect).init();

Comment: @PhillPafford: That's about what I have as well, still don't quite understand the initialization of the UI. Trying to figure it out. There was supposedly a method called `.customerSelect()` that you could call off the element, but that seems to have disappeared with the later versions.

Comment: found this but not getting the syntax right: $(newSelect).fieldcontain('refresh');

Comment: @PhillPafford: Yea, I'm not even sure. I've gone through this and there are so many objects, private methods, etc. it would take me all day to get my head in the game and be able to know where everything relates. I would say given you have to code to add multiple selects now, post a new question and see if anyone has an answer to dynamic themeing of controls *after* jquery mobile has already ran the init (basically you want something like `$.Widget._createWidget()` called on the new element(s), but also a way to delete/remove them).

Comment: @PhillPafford: Sorry I can't be more help, out of my element with jQM.

Comment: NP, understandable and thanks for all the efforts. When I find the answer I will be sure to post back

Comment: @PhillPafford: You're welcome, and good luck! -- EDIT: Yes, please do. I'd be curious if there is a way. (Also look on github if there already exists a suggestion or if you need to create one for this kind of functionality--I can see it very helpful with how dynamic webpages are these days).

Comment: Sey to bother you with this again, but I did see this: http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/faq.html But still no luck in implementation

Comment: @PhillPafford: Interesting. Maybe you can play with the [CSS] classes it attaches to the page div, assuming that's what it uses as an "already been processed" flag. (Remove the class and re-call `.page` (or so I'm hypothesizing))

Comment: Found the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/UcrD8/45/ also one small note: Need to use jQuery 1.5.1 and not jQuery 1.5 Again thanks for all the help

Comment: @PhillPafford: Wow, congrats! Great job being persistent! ;-) No problem, glad to help out and glad you got what you were looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this...

http://jsfiddle.net/RaHhY/34/

You were setting a change handler for the `id` and not for each `select` that gets created.

Comment: @Phill You're welcome. If you feel this answer is the correct one, please accept it as the correct answer. I needs my reputation :)

Comment: it does work in the example but I have another issue. I'm using the JQM (jQuery Mobile) lib and it's not liking the live(), causes the script to pause on the action of selecting the option. Would there be some alternative syntax for that? could I revert back to the change() somehow?